# Netbeans swing not displaying components correctly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcomponent

Hello I have this weird problem with my laptop Windows 8 64 bit. Netbeans is not showing the swing components correctly.
http://postimg.org/image/qdean40pb/
As you can see the text is not clear(HOST,connect button,disconnect button) and I can't find a reason for this.
I thought maybe this is a problem with netbeans 8.0 so I tried installing 7.3 and I had the same problem even with the installer itself.(The next button and other text)
http://postimg.org/image/3nf5u4hhr/

I am using netbeans 7.3 on my desktop windows 7 32 bit with no such problem.
Can you please help me ?
Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is running the NetBeans IDE using the High Performance NVIDIA processor not the Integrated graphic card. You can choose that option in Windows 8 by right-clicking on the NetBeans IDE icon before starting it then hover on Run with graphic processor and choose your High Performance graphic card.